# To get some part of html page to be non-scrollable and invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

there is a html page of `400vh` height and divided into two parts. I want the first part to be hidden and importantly non-scrollable by having a button
for that, the way once the user clicks the button, second part supersedes the first and the whole hight turns to `200vh` so that only the second part is visible and scrollable.
how to do so?

Comment: Would you mind supplying a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.. What have you tried to solve this on your own? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service...

Answer (score 1):

Requirement is not very clear. But I guess you would hide the first div with css

`diplay: none`

then you would have the second div set as:

`overflow-y: auto`

And if this has to be done with a button, on click, link a js method which would update the style attributes to the desired css elements.